# OpenJPA produces incorrect query despite an annotation

Tags: java, jpa, db2, openjpa

I have an hierarchy of buildings/floors/rooms in my application. Whenever I'm trying to add the floor (with `entiryManager.persist(floor)`) I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-798, SQLSTATE=428C9, SQLERRMC=FLOOR_ID, DRIVER=3.68.61 {prepstmnt 925512112 INSERT INTO ROOMALLOCATION.Floor (FLOOR_ID, FLOOR_NAME, FLOOR_CODE, SITE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=-798, state=428C9]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLRI079, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -95, 0]
```

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-798, SQLSTATE=428C9, SQLERRMC=FLOOR_ID, DRIVER=3.68.61
FailedObject: com.RoomAllocation.entities.Floor@1d32457

On the floor object, specifically FLOOR_ID:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "FLOOR_ID")
private int floorId;
```

The field in database is GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.

Same setup works for buildings and rooms, I used the same code to create and persist objects. As far as I understand openJPA supposed to put `DEFAULT` in the query, instead of this it's putting 0, because it's int default value. Is there a way to fix it? Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` to `@Column` annotation I succeeded to stop this behavior.